# Qt 5.2 / OpenCV 2.4.8 - Can’t open video files via VideoCapture

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ffmpeg, qtgui

I have a big problem that i can’t solve by myself. OpenCV itself works fine, but i’m not able to load videos. Here’s my code:

PRO- File

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = videoredux
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV/opencv_bin/install/include
LIBS += -LC:\\OpenCV\\opencv_bin\\bin \
    libopencv_core248d \
    libopencv_highgui248d \
    libopencv_imgproc248d \
    libopencv_features2d248d \
    libopencv_calib3d248d \
    libopencv_video248d \


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

and the MainWindow Class:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <iostream>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->videoStatusLabel->setText("Kein Video geladen.");

    // SIGNALS & SLOTS

    QObject::connect(ui->chooseVideoButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 this,SLOT(chooseVideo()));
    QObject::connect(ui->startButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 this,SLOT(startProcess()));

}

void MainWindow::chooseVideo(){

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
         tr("Open Video"), "/home", tr("Video Files (*.avi *.mp4 *.mpeg *.mpg)"));
    qDebug() << "Path:" << fileName;
    ui->videoStatusLabel->setText(fileName);
}

void MainWindow::startProcess(){
    QString videoPath = ui->videoStatusLabel->text();
    QFileInfo video(videoPath);
    if(video.exists()){
        const std::string path = videoPath.toUtf8().constData();
        cv::VideoCapture capture(path);
        cv::Mat frame;

        if(!capture.isOpened()){
            qDebug() << "Error, video not loaded";
        }

        cv::namedWindow("window",1);
        while(true)
        {
            bool success = capture.read(frame);
            if(success == false){
                break;
            }
            cv::imshow("window",frame);
            cv::waitKey(20);
        }
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "Error, File doesn't exist";
    }
}
```

The paths are correct, I tried many different video formats but he never loads the videos. I’m running Qt on a Windows 8 machine and i have “K-Lite Codec Pack 10.2.0 Basic” and ffmpeg installed. The videos are playing properly with my video players. I also tried to copy the .dll to the working directory, searched for opencv dll's in the system32 directory and rebuild OpenCV with mingw on this computer. I know that many people have the same problems, but none of their suggestions solved it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Nadine

----UPDATE---- I still can't open video files, so I programmed the application on a Windows7 64-Bit system. It worked fine, but when I try to open the application on a Windows8 computer it still can't open the file. It doesn't matter which codecs are installed, because it generally runs on every Windows7 computer and fails on every Windows8 computer.. The same for older OpenCV-Versions. Is there a general problem with OpenCV and Windows8?

Comment: "but none of their suggestions solved it" -> Please elaborate what exactly you have tried. Off-topic: `QT       += core gui` can be deleted  since core and gui are added by default. Funny :) `ui->videoStatusLabel->setText("Kein Video geladen.");` You may want to use QObject::tr() instead.

Comment: The `/home` is also badly hard-coded. At any rate, are you getting this error or which one? "Error, video not loaded"?

Comment: Oh sorry, all the things I already tried are listed in the text =) These are: Installing new codecs, trying different video formats, copy dll's to working directory, rebuilding OpenCV (I also checked if I missed the "WITH_FFMPEG" option, but I didnt).. and so on. I'm close to despair =(

Comment: Yes, he always says that it isn't loaded.

Comment: The path contains the correct string as you expect? Have you tried printing that out?

Comment: Yes, the paths are correct. I also tried to give VideoCapture the path directly. I don't have this problems with image files..

Comment: So what happens if you write a simple main.cpp with         `cv::VideoCapture capture("/path/to/stuff"); if(!capture.isOpened()){ ...}`

Comment: It doesnt work either. So, I think perhaps something went wrong while compiling OpenCV.. in the standard build which comes with OpenCV there is a ffmpeg-directory in 3rdparty. In my build there isn't one? Like you already know, i'm not very experienced with Qt and OpenCV.. =(

Comment: So, does it work if you use the "standard" build?

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit Windows? I'm using 64-bit Win 7, and have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it's an 64-Bit Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if somebody is still needing an answer, but here is how I solved this problem.

I simply copied the opencv_ffmpegXXX.dll into the directory with the .exe-file. It took me days to find that out. Thanks for all your answers and help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Now it is solved. We need to install correct Codecs following the suggestion from OpenCV at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html. Check the VideoWriter::VideoWriter section. We need Video Codecs by FOURCC at http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php. Be careful. The installation may install garbage as well as codecs. Not all codecs are recognized. At least now I have mpeg4 and DivX and can open Megamind.avi, used by OpenCV's own demo program.